# como pegar uma sequencia correta no order by mysql?

Tags: mysql

tem uma sequência de números 1 à 20 eu gostaria de saber se tem como pegar a sequencia de numero correta por exemplo:

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...

como essa query select * from tabela order by numero asc;

ele pega assim:

1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20...

tem uma maneira de pegar a primeira sequencia que mostrei acima usando o order by

ja tentei usar um field para o order by não deu certo

Comment: O melhor mesmo seria arrumar a coluna pro tipo certo. Se são só números, não devia ser CHAR/VARCHAR.

Comment: A coluna que possui essa sequencia de números está no tipo numerico?

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY CAST(coluna_numero AS unsigned) ASC`

Comment: juliano sua dica deu certo valeu

Answer (score 1):

Podem existir outras maneiras de resolver isso,
mais você pode tenar da seguinte forma:

> SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(id), id